# Type or namespace name 'async' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

In VS2012.2 I have a week-old ASP.NET MVC 4 app targeting .NET 4.5 that, if I use the `async` keyword, works as expected.

In a class library project created around the same time, targeting 4.5, I cannot use the `async` keyword.

So I created a new ASP.NET MVC 4 (4.5) web app project and again I am unable to use `async`

> Type or namespace name 'async' could not be found

It's one of those problems where I feel like I'm doing something totally stupid. Afterall, I was in Le Mans watching the race and drinking all weekend.

I mean, it should just work in any .NET 4.5 project right? Its a compiler feature.

Comment: Could you tell us more about Le Mans or where in the code you put "async"?

Comment: :) I could enthuse about Le Mans all day, although if you go, expect not to have a functioning brain for a week.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Blimey. It was something stupid, just didn't add the void or the return type! Obviously `async` is interpreted as a type since I didn't include one. I could delete my question, but I'm happy to look like a fool if it helps others ;)

Comment: The error message didn't make it obvious, I think it gives a point to your question.

Comment: This just happened to me. I feel so stupid. Coincidentally, I was under similar brain-numbing affects as you described :P

Comment: And it just happened to me too, which is why I arrived at this page :P More specifically, I was prefixing my method with `Task<void>` when I should have been writing just `Task` instead.

Comment: I had the type. was missing the method name though : static async Task ()

Comment: exactly what happened to me, thanks for your answer !!